# Dialogflow Google Calender integration "Error: No handler for requested intent at WebhookClient.handleRequest"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api, dialogflow-es

I did the Google Calender Integration in Dialogflow using the Fullfillment.
When I test the action I get the following error within the Google Cloud Platform

```
Error: No handler for requested intent
    at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/workspace/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:317:29)
    at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/workspace/index.js:62:8)
    at cloudFunction (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
    at process.nextTick (/layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/invoker.js:100:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

This is my cloud function code - the name of the used intent is "book.appointment"

```
'use strict';

// Import the Dialogflow module from Google client libraries.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');


// Set up Google Calendar Service account credentials
const serviceAccountAuth = new google.auth.JWT({
 email: serviceAccount.client_email,
 key: serviceAccount.private_key,
 scopes: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
});

const calendar = google.calendar('v3');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements

const timeZone = 'Europe/Berlin';
const timeZoneOffset = '+02:00';

// Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request.
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
 console.log("Parameters", agent.parameters);
 const appointment_type = agent.parameters.AppointmentType;
 function makeAppointment (agent) {
   // Calculate appointment start and end datetimes (end = +1hr from start)
   const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0] + timeZoneOffset));
   const dateTimeEnd = new Date(new Date(dateTimeStart).setHours(dateTimeStart.getHours() + 1));
   const appointmentTimeString = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString(
     'en-US',
     { month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone }
   );
    // Check the availability of the time, and make an appointment if there is time on the calendar
   return createCalendarEvent(dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointment_type).then(() => {
     agent.add(`Ok, let me see if we can fit you in. ${appointmentTimeString} is fine!.`);
   }).catch(() => {
     agent.add(`I'm sorry, there are no slots available for ${appointmentTimeString}.`);
   });
 }

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'book.appointment'.
 let intentMap = new Map();
 intentMap.set('book.appointment', makeAppointment);
 agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});

//Creates calendar event in Google Calendar
function createCalendarEvent (dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, appointment_type) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   calendar.events.list({
     auth: serviceAccountAuth, // List events for time period
     calendarId: calendarId,
     timeMin: dateTimeStart.toISOString(),
     timeMax: dateTimeEnd.toISOString()
   }, (err, calendarResponse) => {
     // Check if there is a event already on the Calendar
     if (err || calendarResponse.data.items.length > 0) {
       reject(err || new Error('Requested time conflicts with another appointment'));
     } else {
       // Create event for the requested time period
       calendar.events.insert({ auth: serviceAccountAuth,
         calendarId: calendarId,
         resource: {summary: appointment_type +' Appointment', description: appointment_type,
           start: {dateTime: dateTimeStart},
           end: {dateTime: dateTimeEnd}}
       }, (err, event) => {
         err ? reject(err) : resolve(event);
       }
       );
     }
   });
 });
}
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance, Bianca

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Does seem like an odd problem. It would help if we can see a screen shot of the Intent that you think should be triggered. You may also want to log the `request.body` and post that, since it might post some insight.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRE6i.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPnys.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEqyh.png

Answer (score 0):

You've to split with '+' instead of '-' in :

```
const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1].split('-')[0] + timeZoneOffset));
```

because you have timeZoneOffset is '+02:00'

Or try changing all that to :

```
const dateTimeStart = new Date(Date.parse(agent.parameters.date.split('T')[0] + 'T' + agent.parameters.time.split('T')[1]));

 
const dateTimeEnd = new Date(new Date(dateTimeStart).setHours(dateTimeStart.getHours() + 1));
     
const appointmentTimeString = dateTimeStart.toLocaleString(
      'en-US',
      { weekday: 'short', day: 'numeric', month: 'short', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', timeZone: timeZone }
    );
```

I hope this works, because it did for me.